# How to inherit js file tax_group.js (account) in odoo 13

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overwrite, odoo-13

I need to add another state to a function in account/static/src/js/ tax_group.js line 94

var displayEditWidget = self._isPurchaseDocument() && this.record.data.state === 'draft' && this.getParent().mode === 'edit';

I already added inheritance to web.assets_backend but don't know how to exactly overwrite the function.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thank you very much

Paul

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, Because the js refers to the field of a record:

```js
...this.record.data.state
```

To add a new state value, you just have to add a new state in the corresponding python field "state" of the account.move model:

1. in your `__manifest__.py` file, you should add the `account` module in the `depends` section:

```py
depends: ['account'],
```

2. in a new file in your custom module>models>my_account_move.py: inherit the model and add a new value to the existing `state` field:

```py
    class AccountMove(models.Model):
        _inherit = "account.move"

        # in the original model located in addon: account/models/account_move.py: 
        # state = fields.Selection(selection=[('draft', 'Draft'),('posted', 'Posted'), ('cancel', 'Cancelled')], string='Status', required=True, readonly=True, copy=False, tracking=True, default='draft')

        state = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('mynewstate', 'My New   State')])
```

**After this python customization, if you really need to override the js:**

In you custom module ("my_custom_module"),

in a new js file, you should call the original js class and using include to "patch" it this way:

```js
    odoo.define('my_custom_module.my_tax_group', function (require) {
        "use strict";
    
        var core = require('web.core');
        var _t = core._t;
    
        var TaxGroupCustomField = require('account.TaxGroupCustomField');
    
    
        TaxGroupCustomField.include({ 

    /**
     * To override an original function 
     * @private
     * @override
     */
    _render: function (){
        var res_original = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        //var displayEditWidget = self._isPurchaseDocument() && this.record.data.state === 'draft' && this.getParent().mode === 'edit';
        
        
    },

});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The new state is already implemented and working, also I set the depend in my module. Thanks for the js code I'll test immediately and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Consider up-voting my answer please :-)

Comment: I need the adjustment in js because in standard in state draft the tax_amount could be edited which is controlled by the js and thsi should be also possible in my extra state

Comment: I need to overwrite/extend the js so it also displays the edit widget in state reviewed and not only in state draft ...

Comment: TaxGroupCustomField.include({ 

        /**
         * To override an original function 
        
         */
         
        var displayEditWidget = self._isPurchaseDocument() && this.record.data.state === 'draft' && this.getParent().mode === 'edit';
            
        _render: function (){
            var res_original = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
           
            
        },
    })
});